# Write HTML tag inside Javascript text

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle

I have a Javascript function that prints "like" and "Unlike" like this:

```
 $(".liketoggle").click(function () {
     $(this).text(function(i, v){
         return v === 'Like' ? 'Unlike' : 'Like'
     })
 });
```

I have an **HTML** tag that shows a heart in an  tag as:

```
<i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
```

How can I show the heart icon next to the like/unlike button. This is the HTML so far:

```
<button type="submit" 
        class="btn btn-custom btn-sm liketoggle" 
        name ="like">Like
</button>
<i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
```

How I can write to the **JS** to be included when toggling it?

Similar Function here: http://jsfiddle.net/dFZyv/ but same issue

Comment: Are you asking how to show/hide the fa-heart when the button is clicked?

Comment: my question is to keep the icon on click beside the like/unlike text @ChrisG

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/apbknwgf/

Comment: @JawadSleiman Why would you show the same icon for 2 different states? Perhaps you could show a white heart (with just a solid outline) instead of a filled heart or the unlike, and toggle between those?

Comment: Changed: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/apbknwgf/12/